# Javascript functions overriden prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, function, object, prototype

I've found some interesting examples on SO. Among them was link to this [article](http://www.mollypages.org/misc/js.mp).
 It's said that:

> `Function.__proto__` points to `Function.prototype`. This results in:

```
 Function.constructor === Function
```

> That is to say: Function is it's own constructor!

```
Object instanceof Object == true.
```

This is because:

```
Object.__proto__.__proto__.constructor == Object
```

> Note also that unlike `Object instanceof Object`, `Foo instanceof Foo == false`.
>   This is because: `Foo` does not exist as a constructor for it's own prototype chain.

From Mozilla developer network I've found out that both prototypes and constructor functions can easily be overriden. And since [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) just checks `constructor.prototype` in prototype chain, I don't really get why my code still returns `false`.

```
function Foo() { } ;
Foo.prototype = Foo
Foo.constructor = Foo
Foo instanceof Foo // still false
```

There a little quetions on prototypes also. Did I get it right, that prototype itself is a separate auxillary object? And this object is like a pointer on another object - usually `Object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj instanceof` does not look for `constructor` in `obj.prototype`, but in the object's internal `__proto__` property.

Every object in javascript has an internal `__proto__` property which references the object's prototype. When an object is constructed using the `new` operator, that object's internal `__proto__` property is set to the constructor's `prototype` property.

Thus, when you say `Foo instanceof Foo`, the javascript VM will look for "Foo" in `Foo.__proto__`. Because Foo is a function, `Foo.__proto__` is `Function.prototype` (where  `Function` is the constructor of functions).

Since you cannot actually change an object's internal `__proto__` property, Foo can never be an instance of Foo.

---

About your little question: in javascript, everything is an object. This includes prototypes **and** functions. In fact, ECMAScript 5 added a function `Object.create` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)) which takes an object as its first parameter, and in turn creates a new object using the first object as its internal prototype object.

Comment: Hmm... Could someone tell me how to turn the bold __proto__ into _ _ proto _ _ ?

Comment: Sorry for an overlapping answer, yours was a good one. I don't know how to escape the bold markdown, other than wrapping it in a code segment, like you've done earlier in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer, indeed it is. I've tried to change `__proto__`  and JS VM showed and error of cycling of objects.

Comment: @Johnny_D `__proto__` chains can never be cyclic. If you look up a property in an object (e.g. `obj.value`) but that property isn't there, it's looked up in object's `__proto__`. If the property isn't there either, `__proto__.__proto__` is looked up, until the property is found or `__proto__` is null. With cyclic prototype chains, this would cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Agreed, but it's somehow hadnled in case of `Function` object

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that an object's actual, internal prototype reference that is part of the prototype chain is not the same thing as the object's prototype *property*. An object's internal prototype is set to its constructor's prototype *property*.

The article I found most comprehensible when learning this was actually [this one](http://beej.us/blog/data/javascript-prototypes-inheritance/).

In other words, the only point in changing the `prototype` property of an object is if that object is a function that should be used as a constructor. Other than that, there's nothing magical about it, it's just a property. Changing `prototype` doesn't change `__proto__` and will not affect an object's prototype chain.

So, going through the code:

```
function Foo() {}
```

Foo's constructor is actually Function at this point, and Function.prototype is Foo's actual, internal prototype, or `__proto__` if you will.

```
Foo.prototype = Foo;
```

This only changes Foo's prototype *property*, but not it's internal prototype.

```
Foo.constructor = Foo
```

This actually only sets the constructor property on Foo, it does nothing with Foo.prototype.constructor and it doesn't do anything with Foo's internal prototype's constructor either, which is what `instanceof` checks.

---

Try this sequence of code, hopefully it will be a bit clearer:

```
function Foo() { } ;

(Foo.prototype != Function.prototype && Foo.__proto__ == Function.prototype);

Foo.prototype = Foo;

(Foo.prototype == Foo && Foo.__proto__ != Foo && Foo.__proto__ == Function.prototype);

Foo.constructor = Foo;

(Foo.constructor == Foo && Foo.prototype.constructor == Foo && Foo.__proto__.constructor != Foo);
```

Comment: Thanks an article and comments, now it looks neater for me.

Comment: Seems that in last you example should be `Foo.prototype.constructor == Foo`

Comment: Yes, thanks. A function's prototype.constructor is always the function itself, unless changed explicitly.